# Is it possible to do a chemical analysis of an urolith that isn't exactly fresh?

Tags: tests

Connected to [this](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/38278/stuck-with-incomplete-diagnosis-for-a-cat-struvites-confirmed-infection-cannot) but isn't part of the same question.

So, it seems my cat is going into surgery in the foreseeable future, but there's literally no one in the country who would do a chemical analysis of the removed stones, so my options are to either not do it at all, send the stones to a Russian vet lab through 9 circles of sanctions hell, or keep the stones and hope I can analyse them when I move to EU, which I have no idea when that'll happen, but even in the ideal world best case scenario it won't be less than 5 months. Would the stones keep that long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will keep. Let it dry completely, then put it in a small, protective container. As long as it's completely dry and not constantly exposed to new air or bacteria, it will be mostly unaffected by time.

Humans who pass kidney stones often don't bring them to the lab right away; they are just told to save them and bring them in at their convenience. However (in humans), not knowing what the composition of the stone is, it's hard to advise them about preventative measures, so sooner is a lot better than later.

Comment: Thank you! I know that the crystals in the urine are struvites, so at least there's that.